# Node.JS: export data from mysql to excel using alasql

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, alasql

I'm writing a script to export data from mysql to excel using Node.JS and [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). I can see [examples in doing this](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Xlsx#xlsx---excel-2007).

```
var mystyle = {
  headers:true, 
  column: {style:{Font:{Bold:"1"}}},
  rows: {1:{style:{Font:{Color:"#FF0077"}}}},
  cells: {1:{1:{
    style: {Font:{Color:"#00FFFF"}}
  }}}
};
alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("restest280b.xls",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,data]);
```

However, there is no documentation about what the variable `data` is and how I should construct it, particular in my case using recordset from mysql?

```
conn.query(SQL, function(err, rows, fields) {
    ALASQL('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("restest280b.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,rows]); 
})
```

I tried to use mysql recordset directly. It wrote a file but can't be opened in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `data` is a array or JSON objects, for example:

```
var rows = [{a:1, b:10, c:'One'}, {a:2, b:20, c:'Two'} ];
alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("restest280b.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[mystyle,rows]);
```

If you use node-mysql package, your code should work.

XLSXML() function generates XML file, and usually Windows version of MS Excel produce a warning. You can aliminate it if you will use XLSX() function with js-xlsx library:

```
var rows = [{a:1, b:10, c:'One'}, {a:2, b:20, c:'Two'} ];
alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("restest280b.xlsx") FROM ?',[rows]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I worked it out earlier and indeed this is the way